# ReactJS - Parents states passed as shallow copy or deep copy to Children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory

So, as we know, the differences between Shallow Copy to Deep Copy is:
**shallow copy**

```
a=5;
b=a; // b point to a's address in the memory. if a changes, b changes.
```

**deep copy**

```
 a=5;
 b=a; // b holds the actual value 5. if a changes, b remains the same.
```

Cool, now, my question is:
Does **passing states** as props to children consider to be **'deep' copy or 'shallow' copy**?

I tend to think it is a deep copy, and then another question raises - isn't that wasteful in resources?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing state as props doesn't copy anything at all. The exact same value is used in both places. For a tiny example:

```js
let parentObj;
const App = () => {
    const [parentStateObj, setParentStateObj] = React.useState({ prop: 'val' });
    parentObj = parentStateObj;
    return <Child obj={parentStateObj} />;
};
const Child = ({ obj }) => {
    console.log(obj === parentObj);
    return 'foo';
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

This is somewhat similar to your comment in the first snippet that

> // b point to a's address in the memory. if a changes, b changes.

except that

- No copying occurs
- If one of the values is *reassigned* (in the parent or child), that won't have any effect on the other value - reassigning a variable, by itself, has no side-effects
- If one of the values is *mutated* (in the parent or child) - while the change will be visible in both components if you set things up to observe it - you should [never mutate state in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997). Rather, you should call the state setter with the new state, which will then trigger a re-render.

---

Shallow copying usually refers to one of the following, which actually creates a separate array or object:

```
const shallowCopyArr = [...arr];
const shallowCopyObj = { ...obj };
```

Deep copying refers to recursively iterating over every nested value in an object or array to create a new one and is [somewhat more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript).

Comment: People as yourself make this website just purely awesome. Thanks for the detailed answer, was insightful and fun reading.